# C# Search filters- ignore specific diacritics

Tags: c#, linq, diacritics

I'm writing a program, and I'm using a LINQ search to a SQL Server database (although this is probably subject to change at some point). I want to make filters for certain diacritics, e.g search for tilde ẽ but not circumflex ê. I've seen examples of how to ignore all, but none saying how to ignore specific ones. Will I just have to convert all strings searched manually by iterating through the strings and changing them?

Comment: I would  create a dictionary/lookup of diacritics that would be filtered and compare each character of your string with the dictionary/lookup.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: nevermind I misread your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database collation permits it, you have to write a method to ignore specific characters.

If you want to ignore ALL diacrits you have to define your own method like :

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this String s)
{
    String normalizedString = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
    {
        Char c = normalizedString[i];
        if (System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

EDIT:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool CaseContains(this string baseStr, string textToSearch, StringComparison compareMode)
    {
        return (baseStr.IndexOf(textToSearch, compareMode) != -1);
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
if(text.CaseContains(whattextisearch, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
.....
```